# Grouping: create new column and group categories that only appear once into a 'catch all' category

Tags: plot, group-by

I want to group my data into categories and plot it. Basically I want to show the top 5 on their own and then the rest as 'Other smaller locations' or similar category.
[Example of what I have vs what I want to see](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q7Z3f.png)

Thanks,
Leah

I did Groupby and it grouped the larger categories together which is great, but I need to be able to group all the smaller ones together so I don't have thousands of lines to plot.